# Locate a specific text in excel worksheet using vb.net and returning the row or column it’s in

Tags: excel, vb.net

I’m trying to find the location of two different texts on an Excel worksheet. The first one I need to find the row number where the text is at. The second one I need the column where that text is at. Both the row number and column are used later for updating the Excel worksheet.
I’ve only tried searching for the row so far and that is not working.

```
Private Sub XlCheck() 'This updates excel spreadsheet
    Dim appXL As Excel.Application
    Dim wbXL As Excel.Workbook
    Dim shXL As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader("C:\Users\OneDrive\Documents\dir.txt")
    Dim strSR As String = sr.ReadLine
    Dim range As Excel.Range

    appXL = CreateObject("excel.application")
    appXL.WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlMinimized

    wbXL = appXL.Workbooks.Open(strSR & "Copy.xlsm")
    shXL = wbXL.Worksheets("Adjustments")

    range = shXL.UsedRange

    With shXL
        range = .Range("B1:B8").Find(What:="Discover", LookIn:=xlValues).row
    End With

    wbXL.Close()
    appXL.Quit()

End Sub
```

I get an error message: ‘xlValues’ is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to it’s protection level.

Comment: Is there a certain NuGet package you are using to get the Excel reference? Or are those custom classes?

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use the Object Browser (View Menu->Object Browser), it is your friend when you need to find where such values are defined.

Enter `xlValues` in the search bar.  Then click the "Search" button to the right of the search bar (a magnifying glass icon in recent VS versions).

[image]

You can then see that it is a menber of the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFindLookIn` enum.

Full reference: `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues`

Answer (score 0):

I just found an answer that works.
replace

```
       'range = .Range("B1:B8").Find(What:="Discover", LookIn:=xlValues).row'
```

with

```
        range = .Range("B1:B8").Find("Discover")
        Dim row As String = range.Row

        range = .Range("C1:N1").Find("JUN")
        Dim col As String = range.Address
```